# How to build efficient Kafka broker healthcheck?

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka

In my app I will perform some kind of health check of my Kafka cluster.

Currently I make a `TopicMetadataRequest` to detect dead brokers:

```
  Future {
    // this will fail if Kafka is unavailable
    consumer.send(new TopicMetadataRequest(Seq("health-check-topic"), 1))
  }
```

Unfortunately this call produces a huge network traffic, because of Cluster topology/settings.

Is there a better way to check kafka brokers? What I need is something simple like `true/false` indicator.

Comment: Just a thought, but might this question be better homed on Server Fault?

Comment: Moving from answer to comment - https://github.com/andreas-schroeder/kafka-health-check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you to use Yahoo Kafka Manager, which provides all the information related to Kafka setup. (e.g. bytes sent/consumed over a time interval).  This tool can also be used for managing your Kafka Cluster.

It also exposes Restful API and you can consume these API in your own application, if needed. Follow the following link to access it.

https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager

Comment: Thank you. The one problem with this library is that you can't use it as lib dependency in my project. It have to be deployed separately. But it is a nice lib :)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to build your own health check, this is a current (January 2020) list of [KIPs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Improvement+Proposals) covering health checks:

- [KIP-143: Controller Health Metrics](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-143%3A+Controller+Health+Metrics)
- [KIP-188: Add new metrics to support health checks](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-188+-+Add+new+metrics+to+support+health+checks)
- [KIP-237: More Controller Health Metrics](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-237%3A+More+Controller+Health+Metrics)

Regarding [Harvinder Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4288096/harvinder-singh)'s [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31514357):

[Kafka Manager](https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager) is great but it's [evolving slowly](https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager/issues/586). There's of course [Confluent Control Center](https://www.confluent.io/confluent-control-center/) - a part of Confluent Platform, but you'll need a license for it. Confluent is a company founded by the team that built Apache Kafka. I've heard about [akHQ (ex KafkaHQ)](https://akhq.io/) ([HackerNews story](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21912254)). Here's a list of management consoles maintained on [Apache Kafka Confluence page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Ecosystem#Ecosystem-SearchandQuery) (check URLs there):

- Kafka Manager - A tool for managing Apache Kafka.
- kafkat - Simplified command-line administration for Kafka brokers.
- Kafka Web Console - Displays information about your Kafka cluster including which nodes are up and what topics they host data for.
- Kafka Offset Monitor - Displays the state of all consumers and how far behind the head of the stream they are.
- Capillary - Displays the state and deltas of Kafka-based Apache Storm topologies. Supports Kafka >= 0.8. It also provides an API for fetching this information for monitoring purposes.
- Doctor Kafka - Service for cluster auto healing and workload balancing.
- Cruise Control - Fully automate the dynamic workload rebalance and self-healing of a Kafka cluster.
- Burrow - Monitoring companion that provides consumer lag checking as a service without the need for specifying thresholds.
- Chaperone - An audit system that monitors the completeness and latency of data stream.

If you don't need GUI, there are also:

- https://github.com/andreas-schroeder/kafka-health-check
- and its fork https://github.com/ustream/kafka-health-check

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Zookeeper API to get the broker list as follows:

```
ZooKeeper zk = new ZooKeeper(KafkaContextLookupUtil.getZookeeperConnect().getZkConnect(), 10000, null);
    List<String> ids = zk.getChildren("/brokers/ids", false);
    List<Map> brokerList = new ArrayList<>();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    for (String id : ids) {
        Map map = objectMapper.readValue(zk.getData("/brokers/ids/" + id, false, null), Map.class);
        brokerList.add(map);
    }
    return brokerList;
```

Comment: This just gets a broker list.. Doesn't actually check clients can communicate **with** the brokers.

Comment: will the list change if some brokers are down?